# Prove that the total order in $\Bbb Q$ is transitive

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, equivalence-relations

Define: $Q := \lbrace [(a, b)] : (a, b) ∈ \Bbb Z × (\Bbb Z \setminus \lbrace0\rbrace)\rbrace= (\Bbb Z × (\Bbb Z \setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace))/R$

Define $R$ to be $((a, b),(c, d)) ∈ R ⇔ ad = bc$

Define $\le$ to be $[(a, b)] ≤ [(c, d)] ⇔ (a · d − b · c) · b · d ≥ 0.$

Prove that $\le $ is transitive.

It seems harder then I expected. Could someone please help me to prove it without using strict total order? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, and $Q$ is the quotient of this set by that equivalence relation, right? Maybe it would be better to first define $R$ since you're using it before defining it, and it can lead to confusion.

Comment: Perhaps this is easier if you define a sum. Notice that this order is not the most straightforward way to replicate the usual order on $\mathbb{Q}$: if we identify $1$ with $[(1,1)]$ and $0$ with $[(0,1)]$, then $1 < 0$.